# Why does already installed ubuntu needs reinstall?

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my laptop. At first everything is going great, but after restart when installation is done, it's telling me that there is no bootable device and if I stick flash drive in, it starts installing ubuntu again over and over.

It's obvious that I have installed ubuntu but after restart everything gets removed that I saved before. Any ideas?

Comment: What is obvious to a human and obvious to a machine are not always the same thing. Take a look [at some of the solutions offered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198117/no-bootable-device-on-single-boot-ubuntu-for-acer-aspire-es14). It might help resolve your issue as well 

Comment: Okay, so as Liam told me I searched everything. My laptop is UEFI, hard disk is something like "GPT with protective MBR. using GPT.". I'm not trying dual boot, I'm just trying to install only ubuntu.

Comment: @Matigo Thank you, I'll see

Answer (score 0):

> It's obvious that I have installed ubuntu but after restart everything gets removed that
> I saved before.

No, it is not obvious. This is a wild guess and I am confident that it is incorrect.

I think that what is happening is that you are not correctly installing a bootloader.

Is your computer BIOS or UEFI?
Is your hard disk MBR or GPT?
Are you trying to dual-boot? If so, with what?
Is your firmware up to date? If not, update it.

If you do not know how to answer these questions, Google them. You will find lots of instructions on how to find these things out. You will need to know the answers and give them to us before we can help you.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It's my first time on linux, so I'll search it up